# Window without border like Corel Draw start up from powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Friends, many a times I saw Corel Draw start up window.
It has no shape; that means it contain balloon shape and
has no border.

I also created start up image and I placed on one window.
Now I want to transparent the areas which are outside
my image.

Its a vb code; if anybody has tried this solution, please let
me know with code.

Answer (score 1):

Usually that is done calling the region function of the Win32 API:

- [Region functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162915%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [SetWindowRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [DeleteObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183539%28VS.85%29.aspx)

First you define the region that you want to keep with `CreateXXXRgn` (you create complex regions using `CombineRgn`) and then activate it with `SetWindowRgn`). You need to call `DeleteObject` to destroy the region object.